# Windows azure connect virtual machinie from different account

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I would like to connect two VM from two different account in Windows Azure.

Is it possible?

Because I've searched in the web and the e.g are only about the same account.

Thank you all for the help

Comment: What do you mean by connecting? You could open ports and communicate over IP/TCP or the service bus?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Azure Connect is per subscription scope. See if the new endpoint to site VPN works for you https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-point-to-site-create/, I haven't tried it.